# Did Voldemort plan to take over the entire world?

Tags: harry-potter

Did Voldemort ever plan to extend his rule to the other wizarding societies outside of Great Britain and then eventually topple the International Statue of Secrecy and take over the Muggle world as well?

Comment: Wormtail:  "Voldy, What do you want to do today?"                                                                                                                       Lord Voldemort:                                           The same thing we do every day, Wormy, Try to take over the world!

Comment: Given that other parts of Europe are significantly friendlier to Dark Arts (Drumstrang teaches them!), the fact that he picked Dumbledore-infested England seems to indicate that he wasn't all that interested in abroad.

Comment: He also traveled abroad without ever trying (as far as we know) getting power there, e.g. Albania.

Answer (score 1):

You can surmise that he had to start somewhere. His greater plans are never revealed but, as with all slaves to power and ambition you can imagine that overall world (universal?) domination would have followed UK domination.

I imagine that, once Harry was dead then nothing would stand between him and UK domination. Replace the ministry of magic with his own mechanisms and then influence and/or conquer the 'other' ministries (I'm assuming that France, Romania, etc.) have their own magical 'governments'.

Can you imagine Voldemort conquering hogwarts and then sitting down with a cup of tea and saying 'time to retire' ?

However, according to the books his main desire was for the post of 'defence against the dark arts' at hogwarts and then, we can speculate, headmaster. But, as stated before, he'd need to broaden his horizons far beyond that . . .

Comment: "[Voldemort's] main desire was for the post of 'defence against the dark arts' at hogwarts" it was?! Where is this from? I thought he had larger aims that that even before the first book.

Comment: It was in one of the books where he came to 'interview' with Dumbledore for the post. Dumbledore speculated from that that Voldemort wanted to teach a new generation.